# jQuery add dynamic content from one element to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding livechat to a website, the problem I have is that it adds dynamic onclick to the page which gets blocked by my CSP policy.

I have managed to work around this by removing the dynamic code and adding my own.

What I cannot figure out is how to grab the link id which can either be

> id="online-icon" or id="offline-icon" and also the span class lhc-text-status text

Client-side is not my strong point, so apologies if the code below is a mess, but can someone help with adding the above id into my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.status-icon', function () {
        $(this).closest('#lhc_status_container').remove();

        $('<div id="lhc_status_container">' +
            '<a id="NEED TO ADD STATUS HERE" class="status-icon" href="#">' +
            '<span class="lhc-text-status">AND HERE</span>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</div>').appendTo("#liveChatCase");


        $("#online-icon").click(function () {
            return window.lh_inst.lh_openchatWindow();
        });
    });
});
```

Below is an example of how the dynamic code is added to the page.

```
<div id="lhc_status_container">
<a id="online-icon" class="status-icon" href="#" onclick="return lh_inst.lh_openchatWindow()">
<span class="lhc-text-status">Live help is online...</span></a>
</div>
```

UPDATE I now have managed to get the value of id="NEED TO ADD STATUS HERE" but still working on lhc-text-status

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem, the code is below and if anyone can improve on it it would be appreciated as I need to click the live chat div twice before it opens

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.status-icon', function () {
        var statusId = $(this).attr('id');
        var textStatus = $(".lhc-text-status").text();
        $(this).closest('#lhc_status_container').remove();

        $('<div id="lhc_status_container">' +
            '<a id="'+ statusId +'" class="status-icon" href="#">' +
            '<span class="lhc-text-status">' + textStatus +'</span>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</div>').appendTo("#liveChatCase");


        $(".status-icon").click(function () {
            return window.lh_inst.lh_openchatWindow();
        });
    });
});
```

OK fixed the double click issue with amended code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.status-icon', function () {
        var statusId = $(this).attr('id');
        var textStatus = $(".lhc-text-status").text();
       // $(this).closest('#lhc_status_container').remove();

        $('<div id="lhc_status_container">' +
            '<a id="'+ statusId +'" class="status-icon" href="#">' +
            '<span class="lhc-text-status">' + textStatus +'</span>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</div>').appendTo("body");

        return window.lh_inst.lh_openchatWindow();

       // $(".status-icon").click(function () {
       //     return window.lh_inst.lh_openchatWindow();
        //});
    });
});
```

Comment: You may be able to add $(".status-icon").trigger("click") to avoid the 2nd click